# Declare table, insert into table, select distinct

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-insert

I have a table-valued function where there are multiple tables being declared and finally joined together to create the final table with data from each table. I had a problem with duplicates so I created a new table @ORDERHEADER so select the distinct values and then insert it into the the table and eventually the final table. When I run the select distinct by itself, it populates correctly but when I run it with the insert nothing populates.

Below is the code I am currently working with (I kept the commented out lines for you to see what I have tried -- above the first "--LEFT OUTER JOIN" is my working code).

```
DECLARE @ORDERHEADER TABLE(
    [DIV_CD] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [SALES_ORD_NR] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [CUST_EDP_ID] [decimal](28,0) NOT NULL,
    [OFFER_CD] [varchar] (8) NULL)

    INSERT INTO @ORDERHEADER
    SELECT DISTINCT(SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR), 
SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.DIV_CD, SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.CUST_EDP_ID, 
SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.OFFER_CD
    from SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER
    --join @RETURNS r on SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR = 
--r.SALES_ORD_NR
                --LEFT OUTER JOIN 
--OPENQUERY(CH1KNOWAPP,'SELECT DISTINCT SALES_ORD_NR FROM 
--EmailVPN..EB_RETURN_CONFIRMATION_NEW WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE 
--ORD_ITM_STA_LGCY_CD IN (''R'',''E'',''4'')') as RET_EMAILS on 
--RET_EMAILS.SALES_ORD_NR COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = 
--SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR
    --join @RETURNS r on SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR = 
--r.SALES_ORD_NR
     --join SV_MACORD_RETURNS on 
--SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR = SV_MACORD_RETURNS.SALES_ORD_NR
    -- where exists (SELECT DISTINCT * from 
--SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER)-- exists (select * from SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER 
--join SV_MACORD_RETURNS on SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR = 
--SV_MACORD_RETURNS.SALES_ORD_NR) 
    --where SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR is not null
    --where  SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.OFFER_CD not in ('36')

    where SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR = 'W3151536'
    --group by SV_MACORD_RETURNS.SALES_ORD_NR,  SV_MACORD_RETURNS.DIVISION, --SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.CUST_EDP_ID, SV_MACORD_RETURNS.OFFER_CD
    --having COUNT(SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SRC_SYS_TRANS_DT) < 2
```

Comment: Aside: It looks like you `select` Ord_Nr, Div_Cd, EDP_Id and Offer_Cd, but the columns in the table are Div_Cd, Ord_Nr, EDP_Id and Offer_Cd. The first two columns seem to be swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Test this way... 
You can writing query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR), SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.DIV_CD, SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.CUST_EDP_ID, SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.OFFER_CD
Into #t
from SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER
where SV_OR_1000_ORDER_HEADER.SALES_ORD_NR = 'W3151536'
```

And then perfectly joining by other table...

You can use #table in a session and working by temp table comfortable than variable table.

The end of the query need:

```
 Drop table #t
```

Actually you don't need drop table it's academic advice.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to all columns of the select list. `distinct (a,b),c,d` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a,b,(c),d` or `distinct a,b,c,d`

Comment: I I know it... Give up answer about problem. I don't say any thing about distinct... Just say about use template table and use in join after insert data in #t

Comment: I was able to get it to work. The main reason for my problem was that in another table I had a date range that the record I was looking for was not in. Also, I specified the columns in the insert into and everything populated correctly. Thanks for your help.